# ant compiling libraries seems to be caching swcs

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, ant

I'm massively miffed with this one.  Here's the scenario:

1. I have an ant task which builds and outputs a bunch of swcs
2. The ant task deletes all items in the 'libs' folder, then compiles in order my libraries out outputs them to the 'libs' folder.
3. I have other modules that I compile that depend on these libraries

The problem: I'm having issues where a swc which depends on another swc is compiling against the old version not the one just built in the ant task.

So we compile first common.swc then mydependantswc.swc.  When I compile mydependantswc.swc is compiling against common.swc - the one just built.  When I compile its like common.swc has been cached, it ignores the once just build and compiles against the old version.

I know this happens in flash when you don't delete your old swc libraries before recompiling.  However my ant task deletes those files.  I found that on the mac if I manually went into finder and deleted those libraries off, then compiled, it works fine. Even though the ant task does that, it doesn't work.

Any ideas please? Sounds like this might be a common issue?

Here are some ant code snippets, I think its quite simple ant.

```
<target name="install-libraries" description="standalone build libs">
        <delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
            <fileset dir="${bin.dir}/${managed.libs.dest}"/>
        </delete>
        <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}/${managed.libs.dest}"/>
        <antcall target="compile-libraries"/>
    </target>
```

followed by a standard compc task.

After talking on twitter I suspect it has something to do with the folder structure. You see that one library has a dependency on another compiled library in this folder bin.dir, which is also the folder that I am building to.  I don't know why, but i sense a smell!

Comment: Seen problems on windows where the OS prevents the file from deleted if opened by another process, for example a file editor. I'm not a Mac user, so perhaps someone else can offer something. In the meantime I think some example code demonstrating the problem would really help

Comment: I've been doing ant builds on Mac's for ages, and never noticed this problem. Can you clarify what this means: "if I manually went into finder and binned those libraries off" -- are you deleting the files? If you just run the ant task that deletes the files, what is the exit code from that task? (Obviously it's not failing, but maybe some other status is being reported?) PS: You might want to show the code for the task that deletes the files...

Comment: Some details on the ant tasks would be helpful, what does the clean-up and compilation task look like what actual compiler is being used, are any flags being set (I'm thinking incremental build but I'm much more familiar in Flex than Flash itself).

Comment: @serenskye I've noticed something similar when using ant builds inside Flash Builder. is that your case?

Comment: Okay, sorry for the slowness!  I have updated the post to clarify.  I've also realised that I am also experiencing the problem on my PC. I am using ant via command line!  I am going to try rejigging the structure of the project so I don't have a dependency on a file in the output folder!  Will update if this solves the issue!